# MySQL (Access denied)

Tags: python, mysql, pythonanywhere

Загрузил бота для телеграма на pythonanywhere, также импортировал базу данных (mysql). При запуска бота выдает ошибку

> `"pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1044, "Access denied for user 'Slad'@'%' to database 'blackjack'")"`

Через консоль mysql пытаюсь выполнить

> `GRANT ALL ON *.* to user_name@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

Но выдается уже такая ошибка

> `Access denied for user 'Slad'@'%' (using password: YES)`

Comment: GRANT надо выполнять от имени учётной записи, которая имеет необходимые привилегии для установления прав. Например, от root.

Comment: А как это сделать в pythonanywhere?

Comment: А он тут каким боком? запускайте CLI, подключайтесь к MySQL и выполняйте нужные операции. А питоны - потом, когда с учётными записями и правами разберётесь.